# httpcontext. current.user.identity.name is empty

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

I am trying to compare values of httpcontext.current.user.identity.name with the values stored in my sql database table. It works fine in my local machine. But httpcontext.current.user.identity.name is returning empty when the same website in hosted on server. In IIS "Allow anonymous access" is enabled and i don't want to disable it. There are many solutions available online but i am not able to find the once that's suits my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the AuthCookie?

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtBxusername, txtBxpassword))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(strUsername, true);
    bool isAuth = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; 
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, chkBxRememberMe.Checked);
}
```

Now you should be able to use the following elsewhere in your code:

```
string userName = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I guess this will work in case of forms authentication. Mine is windows authentication.

Comment: You have asp.net specified in your tags for this question and you mention IIS. Where does Windows authentication come into it in your system? I have used asp membership in several projects over the years and can verify that User.Identity.Name will work in ASP.net. Can you provide more details about your set up please?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I am using Asp.net and in web.config file i have set the <authentication mode="Windows"/>.

Comment: Set it to Forms instead of Windows i.e. <authentication mode="Forms"/>

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms"/> <authorization> <allow users ="*"/> </authorization> <identity impersonate ="true"/> This is what i did. But still no luck

Comment: can you post up your web.config settings? If you do not wish to put the whole config up can you give us the Membership, Forms, Profile, RoleManager etc sections of it.

Comment: <membership>
   <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
   </providers>
  </membership>

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

Comment: <profile>
   <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
   </providers>
  </profile>

Comment: <roleManager enabled="false">
   <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
   </providers>
  </roleManager>

Comment: <authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
  <identity impersonate="true"/>